# How to find out if an optional part of a regular expression is captured or not?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

Suppose I have this simple regular expression search piece of code:

```
boost::regex re("(\\d+)(/(\\d))?");
boost::smatch matches;
boost::regex_search(input_str, matches, re);
```

It searches a string for something like `123/2` or `123`. Second digit and  / are optional.
I want to know that if `/2` is present or not and if it exists set the second number after / to a variable or set the variable to -1 otherwise.
I tried to use `matches.size()`, but it's always the same value whether the second part exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups have a boolean `matched` member that you can check.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html

> `m[b].matched` - For all integers n < m.size(), true if sub-expression n participated in the match, false otherwise.